# Question: mysql Subqueries

Tags: sql, mysql

If I run this query:

```
SELECT `Manga`.`id`, `Manga`.`name` FROM `mangas` AS `Manga` WHERE `Manga`.`id` in 
(
SELECT `manga_id` FROM `mangas_genres` where `manga_id` = 1
)
```

My computer does not respond (I just mistype). It can't run this query.
Is the above code invalid? Please, help me.

I think it is valid, but it can't run. I don't understand. It sure be MySQL, I run query on MYSQL workbench (not in PHP) my computer be very slower ( while run query) 
My table mangas and mangas_genres have more than 5000 rows.

Comment: `SELECT 'manga_id' FROM 'mangas_genres' where 'manga_id' = 1` will always return 1 or nothing. I'm guessing that is not the desired outcome. Unless this is some idiom to replace `EXISTS`? What error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My query is valid but lost many time to run query (>100s on my computer , it cause computer to very slower (not responding)),
The solve is index to speed up

Answer (score 2):

That's a valid query, assuming that all table and column names are spelled correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE mangas_genres (manga_id INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO mangas_genres (manga_id) VALUES (1);

CREATE TABLE mangas (id INT NOT NULL, name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO mangas (id, name) VALUES
(1, 'manga1'),
(2, 'manga2');

SELECT `Manga`.`id`, `Manga`.`name` FROM `mangas` AS `Manga` WHERE `Manga`.`id` in
(
SELECT `manga_id` FROM `mangas_genres` where `manga_id` = 1
)
```

Result:

```
id  name
1   manga1
```

Your problem is somewhere else.